# Getting a function to wait for a post middleware save to finish before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, callback, database

Here is my problem i have one worker running that gathers up some data and then saves it to a schema. In those schemas i have post middleware functions that happen on a save. The problem is that my worker does not wait for the post middleware to finish working before it loops and saves again to the same schema. As my worker continues to run it slows down substantially as it queues up those functions over and over again before this get to finish. Those post middleware functions also save to other schemas which also execute there own post functions. SO as i you can tell that starts to really slow down as i am dealing with hundreds of thousands of objects being saved.

## Example of what my code kind of looks likes:

## Worker

```
tranFunc = (stuff, Object) -> 
            newObject = Object
            newObject = new Object newObject
            newObject.save (err) ->
```

The Save now jumps into the schema where some more stuff happens, but my worker loops before that one is done and keeps going

## Schema

```
ObjectSchema.post("save", function() {
 DOING STUFF
```

I have read that i could maybe use something like a `next()` as a callback to the worker but my attempts at using it were not successful.

Comment: Could yo utry to post a "minimal runnable" example please? I think what you need to do is make sure that all your async code is accepting return callbacks like it should but I don't know what is inside what in your examples so I can't tell where you need ot add the callbacks.

Comment: Well thats the problem i don't know how to make a call back so the worker knows my schema is done...my schema is  a separate place ..its not nested wihin the worker incase thats what you thought...

Comment: I tried to give an answer anyway then, see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I can answer this question in its current form but the basic idea is that

1. Async functions should use callbacks to communicate when they are done
2. Functions that call async code are be async themselves.

So in your case, it looks like the worker function is violating this principle, since its calling an async function without being async itself. You would fix this by adding a return callback as a parameter and calling said callbabk after everything is done (that is, inside the callback for the last async method you call)

```
//sort of like this:
tranFunc = (stuff, Object, doneCb) -> 
        newObject = Object
        newObject = new Object newObject
        newObject.save (err) ->
            doneCb( /*put return values here as appropriate*/ )
```

Now whoever is calling `tranFunc` will be able to know when the inner save method has finished.